# Nothing appears in terminal when trying to activate my conda environment

Tags: anaconda, conda, environment

I am trying to create and activate an anaconda environment. To create the environment, I used the following command:

```
(base) C:\Users\sanse> conda create -n myenv python=3.6
```

After this environment was created, I double checked with:

```
(base) C:\Users\sanse> conda info --envs
```

and this listed all my environments, and this new one I just created was in that list.

However, when I type either of the following commands:

```
conda activate myenv
activate myenv
```

, they execute in the prompt, the `(base)` disappears, but the name of the environment, `(myenv)` does not show up, and the prompt is just left as:

```
(base) C:\Users\sanse> conda activate myenv
C:\Users\sanse>
```

I then type in the info command again and it indicates that I am still in the base environment.
What is going on here? How can I activate an environment?

Comment: After `conda activate myenv`, what does `conda info` report is the active environment?

Comment: @merv conda info reports that base is the active environment even though the `'(base)'` is not at the beginning of the prompt anymore.

Answer (score 0):

My computer uses Windows10 OS.

Not long ago, there was no problem.

But nowadays, my 'Anaconda prompt' cannot activate my environment.

If I try to activate an environment, it cannot activate the environment, and (base) disappears.

The prompt returns as below.

```
(base) C:\Users\user>conda activate
C:\Users\user>
```

The deactivation vice versa.

```
(base) C:\Users\user>conda deactivate
C:\Users\user>
```

`conda info` returns

```
(base) C:\Users\user>conda activate DataScience
C:\Users\user>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\user\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\user\.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.2=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (read only)
      conda av data dir : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\user\.conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

'''

It says that the `conda activate` does not work in the 'Anaconda prompt'.

I was wandered for a while, and I tried this using the 'Anaconda PowerShell prompt'.

It succeeded to activate the environment.

Activation via 'Anaconda Navigator' also worked

```
(base) PS C:\Users\user> conda activate DataScience
(DataScience) PS C:\Users\user>

(DataScience) PS C:\Users\user> conda info

     active environment : DataScience
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\DataScience
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\user\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\user\.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.2=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (read only)
      conda av data dir : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\user\.conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

My questions remains:

1. Why the 'Anaconda prompt' is malfunction activating my environment?
2. What difference made 'Anaconda PowerShell prompt' work at the same time?